# how to deactivate jquery according to the viewport size

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a navigation menu that slides out onto the webpage using .animate().  It looks great until the the browser size gets below 1000px.  is there a way to tell jquery to not use the function I created if the viewport is smaller than 1000px, so I can let css take over?

Comment: You could place an if statement around the function that tests the width of the viewport before running the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can desactivate jQuery in CSS, but before you animate you can do that :

```
if($(window).width() > 1000) {
    //animate
}
```

Comment: sorry I dint mean in css.  but that worked.  So simple thanks

Answer (score 1):

I dont't know if there is a nice and small solution for that, but you can check the window width if it is bigger then 1000px and than load the script.

```
if($(window).width() > 1000) {
    $.getScript // http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/
}
```